# How to run one test in two devices doing different actions in each

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am trying to test a procedure involving Nearby interactive communications between two devices. I am not sure to be possible to mock the nearby services involving the communication, and I would like to run the test in two physical devices.

Is it possible to run one test in two devices (doing different things in each one)?

I am using Espresso for other tests, but I think it is not suitable for this. And I do not want to execute manually two different tests in two devices, because there are some synchronization issues that must be observed.